# Validate input field besed on checkbox selection (Custom activity development) in C#

Tags: c#, validation

I want to validate the `TemplatePath` input field if the `Invocietodata` check box is checked and the field is filled.

**Note:** TemplatePath is optional in my input parameter

```cs
[Category("Input")]
public InArgument<string> TemplatePath { get; set; }

[Category("Options")]
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Invocietodata { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you we're talking about server and client side model validation.

Thats how you enable and disable an input field by a checkbox state:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
      if(this.checked) {
         $("#templatePath").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#form").validate(); //sets up the validator
        $("templatePath").rules("add", "required");
      }
      else {
           $("#templatePath").prop("disabled", true);
           $('#templatePath').rules('remove', 'required');
      }       
});
```

You also need to apply validation rules dynamically on checkbox check.
Note: I am using jQuery here.

Comment: template path is .yml template file path,so its optional one. but if check box field is enabled by user this path must be provided.

Comment: @learner i see... your question is unclear, i though you were talking about model validation. I will edit my answer.